# Accessing a playername from oustide a module inside a module

Tags: ruby

im trying to access what the user types in for his/her username that is a function outside of my module so it can be used inside of my module

```
module RetryMessages
    def RetryMessages.message1()
        puts "That was an incorrect Choice #{@your_name}... Try again man."
    end
    MESSAGE2 = "Man you messed up #{@your_name} Try again."
    MESSAGE3 = "Hey man you screwed up..... Try again #{@your_name}."
end


def player_name
    puts "Hey man whats your name?"
    @your_name = $stdin.gets.chomp.upcase
    play_game
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: why doesnt the player name inside my module detect what the user inputs all thru the rest of my code it knows the playername but just not inside the module for some reason .... I can post the rest of the code if need be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a wrong design. Make your messages into templates:

```
MESSAGES = [
  "That was an incorrect Choice %<your_name>s... Try again man.",
  "Man you messed up %<your_name>s Try again.",
  "Hey man you screwed up..... Try again %<your_name>s."
]
```

and then later

```
puts MESSAGES[0] % { your_name: "Joseph" }
```

This way, the place where you're using the name actually has access to it.

Comment: sweet this seems to work at least as far as IRB thanks this might just help ....thanks man and if any one wants to help n try out my game n see any errors i have hit me up

Comment: wait then how does the user name get inputed in to it?

Comment: Using the `%` operator and a replacement array. Every `%<key>s` is replaced by a corresponding value.

Comment: `"#{player_name}"` is equivalent to `player_name`. It's like putting dirt on your apple because it looked clean and Mum told you you need to wash your fruit before eating. :P

Comment: Not annoying, I've been told my kind of humour is "flippant". `puts MESSAGES[2] % { your_name: @your_name }` should suffice, if you have a variable called `@your_name`.

Comment: lol Cool thanks looks like its working how I want it to now....... Thanks I pretty darn new to this stuff but im getting there this was my first question asked on stack too really appreciate the quick response..... The only time i would need to use #{player_name} is when im using it inside of a string is that correct or no?

Comment: Yes. For example, if `player_name` is `"Joseph"`, then `"Hello, #{player_name}!"` will make a new string that says `"Hello, Joseph!"`. `"Hello, %s!" % player_name` does the same, but with a bit more work; `"Hello, " + player_name + "!"` will, again, do the same. Multiple ways to do the same thing. But if `player_name` is a string, you don't need to use `"#{player_name}"` ever, because it just makes busy-work for Ruby without actually doing anything useful - you can just use `player_name`.